# How to put function into my image in svg using d3?

Tags: image, d3.js, svg, button

I have an rectangle and an image in it. I am trying to put a function to the image ( If i clicked it, a link to an website`d appeared ) but i can`t find a proper way.

This is my code

```js
var svgContainer = d3.select("body").append("svg")
                                    .attr("width", 500)
                                     .attr("height", 500);
 
var g = d3.select("svg") .append("g")
 var rectangle = g.append("rect")
                  .attr("x", 0)
                  .attr("y", 0)
                  .attr("width", 300)
                  .attr("height", 200)
                  .style("fill","pink");
                         
 var text = g.append("text")
 .attr("x",150)
 .attr("y",100)
 .attr("text-anchor","middle")
 .text('Nam oc cho')
 
 var img = g.append("image")
 .attr("x",200)
 .attr("y",85)
 .attr("href","firefox.jpg")
 .attr("height","20px")
.attr("width","20px")
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/d3/5.7.0/d3.min.js"></script>
```

Thanks

Comment: Please read about the [The SVG hyperlink element](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/SVG/Element/a) You can wrap the image in a `<a>` element

Comment: What do you mean by function? do you mean a link?